# How to make a sql basis on the Map data

Tags: java, sql

I have my below method which accepts two parameters-

`userId and attributes Map`

attributes Map will have column names and column values-

Let's take an example if I have 5 columns in the above map, then there will be 5 keys and 5 values as well.

so then my SQL will look like this-

`String sql = "INSERT INTO PROFILE(userId, colA, colB, colC, colD, colE) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";`

In the same way, my query statement will look like-

`BoundStatement query = prBatchInsert.bind(userId, colAValue, colBValue, colCValue, colDValue, colEValue);`

But in some case it might be possible that the attributes map will have 20 columns. So basis on that, I need to make sql and query statement.

Below is the code which almost assume that table will have four columns only which is not right.

```
public void upsertAttributes(final String userId, final Map<String, String> attributes) {

    try {
        String[] keys = (String[])attributes.keySet().toArray();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO PROFILE(userId, "+keys[0]+", "+keys[1]+", "+keys[2]+", "+keys[3]+") VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "; 

        BoundStatement query = prBatchInsert.bind(userId, attributes.get(keys[0]), attributes.get(keys[1]), attributes.get(keys[2]), attributes.get(keys[3]));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    }

}
```

How can i write the above method more generic corresponding to the `attributes Map`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Spring jdbctemplate, it has loads of apis for this. Check out this link : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

EDIT:

Check this link : http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-named-parameters-examples-in-simplejdbctemplate/

It exactly does what you want.

EDIT:  If you dont want to use Spring then in order to achieve this you need to generate complete sql string dynamically. Binding will not be used.

See this code[I have not run this code, but this is the basic idea to achieve this]:

```
public void upsertAttributes(final String userId, final Map<String, String> attributes) {

    try {
        String[] keys = (String[])attributes.keySet().toArray();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO PROFILE(userId, "+keys[0]+", "+keys[1]+", "+keys[2]+", "+keys[3]+") VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "; 
        StringBuffer keysStmt = new StringBuffer("INSERT INTO PROFILE("+userId);
        StringBuffer valuesStmt = new StringBuffer("  VALUES (" );

        Iterator itr = attributes.keySet().iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String key = itr.next();
            keysStmt.append(","+key);
            valuesStmt.append(attributes.get(key)+",");          
        }

       //remove last comma
       valuesStmt = new StringBuffer(valuesStmt.toString().substring(0,valuesStmt.length-1));

       sql = keysStmt.append(")")+valuesStmt.append(")");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not using spring template for this particular use case. And also I cannot use it, so that means I need to stick with general solution I guess. But thanks for the link.

Comment: Ok, any particular reason for it? Because it will be like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yeah,I want to avoid extra dependencies as I already have lot of dependency currently in my project and also I believe same thing can be done without that as well.